# How do I set the program session amount by Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I want to send the amount that the program has put in the session at another address as a parameter

```
 $datauser = \App\userazmoon::where('id', '=', 
   Session::get('user_profile'))>first();

 if($datauser != ""){
     $datarec = \App\azmoon::with('category')->find(Session::get('user_az'));
  }else{
     return Redirect::to('/')->with('msgerror','not found');
  }
```

I need for an address that I call

I send the amount of data that is in the server session

Using jmeter

In the image below, two values are entered into the session.

Session :: put ('user_profile', $ find_user-> id);

Session :: put ('user_az', $ request-> get ('inp_x1'));

[image: image one]
And in the picture below I would like to use these sessions

In fact, I can get the amount of session created in the previous address in a

new address by jmeter to handle

[image: image two]

Comment: your question is not clear. you show server code but don't explain which data you want to use on client side. Can you clarify it ? thx

Comment: please show the response you want to extract data from

Comment: In general, my question is how can I get the values at a
The session is filled up with a call at the address B, which I set up in accordance with the code piece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello After a few days I found the answer And send it "Csrf" is on a per request basis.

Of course, the use of headers is also required

HTTP Authorization Manager

HTTP Cookie Manager

HTTP Cache Manager

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract them from the previous response using i.e [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or better [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor), convert into [JMeter Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and substitute hard-coded recorded values with these variables.

The process is known as [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations), you should be able to find a lot of information on it over the web.